# Can't connect to Icloud-Mailserver via Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, icloud

Before today I could connect to the iCloud-Mailserver with the following settings:

```
type: IMAP
server: imap.mail.me.com
username: <my-mail>@me.com
port: 993
security: SSL/TLS
```

However now the client says that my password is incorrect which is not true because I can still login via https://www.icloud.com/#mail

I already contacted the Apple Support but they only recommended that I should update my E-Mail client because they changed some security settings and if it don't works then I should call them back. Which I did but then a Woman sayd to me that I cannot be serious to call the Customer Service from Apple because it has nothing to do with Apple..

I also tried to change the settings to all the recommendations that are on [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304) site

The GMail-App and Outlook can't connect either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this same issue today, after speaking to apple support they advised they have updated their security settings so that all email apps will require the set up of two-factor authentication for an apple ID.

The steps they gave me is to log into your apple account via appleid.apple.com, go to the setting section and click edit - then this should give you the option to enable the two factor authentication.

Comment: It works now.. For anyone interested, after I had setup the two factor authentication I had to create an [App specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397) and removed the `@me.com` from the username